# Wired/Wirless network periodicly disconnects on Ubuntu 20.04, using wicd, and Network-Manager is disabled

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, wicd

Here is what I have tried so far:

first I stopped and disabled Network-Manager so it won't run again after reboot.
I installed WICD, and the problem was partially solved, no more unstable connection over wired or wireless. But the connection is still dropping every hour.

Here is what I have NOT tried:

I read and suspected that this is a router configuration issue but this does not happen over windows on the same device, or any other devices on the network.

A friend suggested downgrading to Ubuntu 18 instead, would that solve the problem?

Back story: the problem started with my macbook pro, the connection suddenly drops and after that the connection never comes back unless I reboot (sometimes I have to reboot many times), I am mentioning this, in case this is a network issue other than a device issue, you tell me.

what can I do?

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Within 4 minutes of WiFi "dropping", `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` might show some useful information. Please [edit] your question to add some of this information, don't use Add comment.

Comment: "I read and suspected that this is a router configuration issue but this does not happen over windows on the same device," A great many things work well in Linux but not Windows and vice-versa. I recommend that you follow up with the router suggestions.